# How do I loop through a large nested list in python?

Tags: python, list, loops, append

I understand how to loop through a single list and a single array. However, I have a nested list and would like to append `lon` with the first element in each nested list in the **same** index before moving onto the next index and repeating the process over until all indexes have been appened.

```
0      [[[-105.077274, 40.514625], [-105.077005, 40.5...
1      [[[-105.024284, 40.509791], [-105.024274, 40.5...
2      [[[-105.087928, 40.578187], [-105.087939, 40.5...
3      [[[-105.11976, 40.589318], [-105.11977, 40.587...
4      [[[-105.083718, 40.568761], [-105.08459, 40.56...
                             ...
995    [[[-105.05362, 40.525161], [-105.053607, 40.52...
996    [[[-105.030003, 40.62114], [-105.030012, 40.62...
997    [[[-105.123316, 40.560645], [-105.123353, 40.5...
998    [[[-105.070162, 40.580083], [-105.070175, 40.5...
999    [[[-105.120617, 40.560044], [-105.120637, 40.5...
Name: geometry_coordinates, Length: 1000, dtype: object
```

Currently, my code is appending `lon` by `index 0` in the first list/element `-105.077274` but instead of staying in `index 0` it loops down to `index 1` and appends `-105.024284` next.

So currently lon looks like `lon=[-105.077274,-105.024284...]` but I am trying to get it to append the `0 index` first, like so `lon=[-105.077274,-105.077005...]` before moving down to `index 1`.

```
import json
import pandas as pd 
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

geojson = json.load(open("Data/Lanes.geojson"))

geojson = json_normalize(geojson['features'], sep="_")

print(geojson['geometry_coordinates'])

lon = []
lat = []

for longitude in geojson['geometry_coordinates']:
    lon.append(longitude[0][0][0])
```

Any help would be appreciated thank you.

Comment: If you have nested lists, use nested loops.

Comment: That's not nested lists, it's a pandas dataframe.

Comment: I knew this looked familiar. Why did you abandon your previous, extremely similar question? I think we still need a bit more information, I don’t really understand what the issue is.

Comment: This was a different way of solving my previous question but unfortunately, it didn't work as intended. But, I learned something new so it's all good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use nested loops.

```
for l1 in geojson['geometry_coordinates']:
    for l2 in l1:
        for l3 in l2:
            lon.append(l3[0])
            lat.append(l3[1])
```

Comment: Awesome thank you! But how did 3 nested loops cover 1000 indexes? Wouldn't I need 1000 nested loops?

Comment: The outer loop processes all the rows.